# flutter/dart Api and WordPress authorization

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I wanted to make connection with my WordPress with API, I successfully made the connection and fetched JSON, here is the connection code

```
// ignore_for_file: avoid_print

import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:testapi/courses.dart';

Future fetchCourses() async {
  String username = "walid.beday";
  String password = "wordpress application password";
  String credentials = "Basic ${base64.encode(
    utf8.encode("$username:$password"),
  )}";
  print(credentials);
  final response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse("https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/sfwd-courses"),
    headers: {"authorization": credentials},
  );
  final responseJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    for (var course in responseJson) {
      print(course["title"]["rendered"]);
      );
    }
    print("Good connetiopn".toUpperCase());
  } else {
    ("bad connection".toUpperCase());
  }
}
```

and this is class Course

```
// ignore_for_file: public_member_api_docs, sort_constructors_first
class Courses {
  String courseTitle;
  int courseId;
  Courses({
    required this.courseTitle,
    required this.courseId,
  });
}
```

I dont know how to take the value from json and add them to course class and return this class in listview builder, here is main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:testapi/courses.dart';
import 'config.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

var courses = [];

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.red),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.backgroundColor,
          elevation: 20,
          title: const Text("Test Api"),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: const FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: fetchCourses,
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: ,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Courses(courseTitle: courseTitle, courseId: courseId);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I dont know what how to ListView.builder to fetch courses

I tried this but didnt work

```
// ignore_for_file: avoid_print

import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:testapi/courses.dart';

Future fetchCourses() async {
  String username = "walid.beday";
  String password = "wordpress application password";
  String credentials = "Basic ${base64.encode(
    utf8.encode("$username:$password"),
  )}";
  print(credentials);
  final response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse("https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/sfwd-courses"),
    headers: {"authorization": credentials},
  );
  final responseJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    for (var course in responseJson) {
      print(course["title"]);
      return Courses(
        courseId: responseJson["id"],
        courseTitle: responseJson["title"]["rendered"],
      );
    }

    print("Good connetiopn".toUpperCase());
  } else {
    ("bad connection".toUpperCase());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do something like this...

First, create a constructor factory on your class (note that I had to make some assumptions about the data when I was casting the json variable):

```dart
class Courses {
  String courseTitle;
  int courseId;
  Courses({
    required this.courseTitle,
    required this.courseId,
  });

  factory Courses.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        return Courses(
          courseTitle: (json['title'] as Map<String, String>)["rendered"] ?? 'Unknown',
          courseId: int.parse((json['id']) as String? ?? '0'),
        );
    }
}
```

Then, change your return type to be a `Future<List<Courses>>`, create an empty list, and populate it with each item you build (note that I did not check your method for accuracy or other issues - I just created the list, cast the results into new `Courses` classes, added them to the list, and returned the list):

```dart
Future<List<Courses>> fetchCourses() async {
  const String username = "walid.beday";
  const String password = "wordpress application password";
  final String credentials = "Basic ${base64.encode(
    utf8.encode("$username:$password"),
  )}";
  print(credentials);
  final response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse("https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/sfwd-courses"),
    headers: {"authorization": credentials},
  );
  final List<Courses> courses = [];
  final responseJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    for (final Map<String, dynamic> course in responseJson) {
      final Courses newCourse = Courses.fromJson(course);
      courses.add(newCourse);
    }
    print("Good connetiopn".toUpperCase());
  } else {
    "bad connection".toUpperCase();
  }

  return courses;
}
```

Next, you need to properly invoke your method using a `FutureBuilder` and doing some basic state handling:

```dart
body: FutureBuilder(
  future: fetchCourses(),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Courses>> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return const CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
        (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.hasError)) {
      return const Text('Error');
    }

    final List<Courses> courses = snapshot.data!;
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: courses.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(courses[index].courseTitle),
        );
      },
    );
  },
),
```

Comment: I get error, i gave you the json data